# why the product of derivative and opposite derivative is 1?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

why does $\frac{dy}{dx}*\frac{dx}{dy}=1$?

I can calculate by using some function, but don't really understand the bigger meaning of this property, what does it represent?

Comment: suppose $y=x$.  Is your formula correct?

Comment: Was that supposed to be $\frac{dy}{dx}*\frac{dx}{dy}=1$?

Comment: yep, made a typo

Answer (score 0):

As lulu implied what you are asserting is simply not true!  Slightly more generally suppose y= ax+ b.  Then dy/dx= a.  Further x= y/a- b/a so dx/dy= 1/a and (dy/dx)(dx/dy)= 1. Was that a typo?  What **is** true is that (dy/dx)(dx/dy)= 1.  One of the things that is typically show early in a Calculus text is that $\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}= \frac{1}{\frac{df(x)}{dx}}$.

Comment: Yes, a typo. it has to be equal to 1. Sorry

Comment: do you have an explanation for this property?

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that the two variable quantities $x$ and $y$ can be related in both ways: $y=\phi(x)$, and $x=\psi(y)$, whereby $\psi=\phi^{-1}$. If $y_0=\phi(x_0)$  we have
$$f(x):=\psi\bigl(\phi(x)\bigr)\equiv x\qquad(x_0-h<x<x_0+h)\ ,$$
since $\phi$ and $\psi$ are inverses of each other. By the chain rule it follows that
$$1=f'(x_0)=\psi'\bigl(\phi(x_0)\bigr)\>\phi'(x_0)=\psi'(y_0)\>\phi'(x_0)\ .$$
Here the RHS is often written as
$${dx\over dy}\biggr|_{y_0}\>{dy\over dx}\biggr|_{x_0}\ .$$